# How can I make an SVG fluid in width and height to be scalable to any size via CSS?

Tags: css, svg

Let's see a simple SVG example from Google Material Symbols (Person icon):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48">
        <path d="M24 23.95q-3.3 0-5.4-2.1-2.1-2.1-2.1-5.4 0-3.3 2.1-5.4 2.1-2.1 5.4-2.1 3.3 0 5.4 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 5.4 0 3.3-2.1 5.4-2.1 2.1-5.4 2.1ZM8 40v-4.7q0-1.9.95-3.25T11.4 30q3.35-1.5 6.425-2.25Q20.9 27 24 27q3.1 0 6.15.775 3.05.775 6.4 2.225 1.55.7 2.5 2.05.95 1.35.95 3.25V40Z" />
    </svg>
```

If I use `style='width: 20px; height: 20px;` it will only show a small part of the person.

If I remote `width` and `height` of the SVG element, then it won't help.

If I use `viewBox`, then it works based on the view box definition. Yet that means that I should spend a lot of time (as someone who is not expert in SVG and rarely uses SVGs) to find out what view box dimensions should I use.

Also `width='100%'` does not help.

My question is this:

Is there a way for me to copy/paste an SVG code, and follow a procedure to make it as neutralize as possible, so that I can only scale it and work with it using CSS?

In other words, I want to be able to define a 100% viewBox for the SVG, and remove width and height, or make the 100% (a repeatable procedure) and then forget about it and style it using CSS.

Is it possible? If yes, what procedure should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

Like you are writing adding a viewBox would be a good solution. And I guess that you would like to maintain some of the padding around the path in the SVG. So, you can just convert the width and height into a viewBox.

1. Past all the SVGs info one HTML document
2. Run the JavaScript below
3. Copy the DOM (I console.log the result in my example) to new files.

Maybe this is a bit too simple of a setup if you have 200 icon, but you get the idea.

```js
var svgs = document.querySelectorAll('svg');

[...svgs].forEach(svg => {
  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${svg.width.baseVal.value} ${svg.height.baseVal.value}`);
  svg.removeAttribute('width');
  svg.removeAttribute('height');
});

console.log([...svgs].map(svg => svg.outerHTML).join('\n'));
```

```css
svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48">
  <path d="M24 23.95q-3.3 0-5.4-2.1-2.1-2.1-2.1-5.4 0-3.3 2.1-5.4 2.1-2.1 5.4-2.1 3.3 0 5.4 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 5.4 0 3.3-2.1 5.4-2.1 2.1-5.4 2.1ZM8 40v-4.7q0-1.9.95-3.25T11.4 30q3.35-1.5 6.425-2.25Q20.9 27 24 27q3.1 0 6.15.775 3.05.775 6.4 2.225 1.55.7 2.5 2.05.95 1.35.95 3.25V40Z" />
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48">
  <path d="M24 23.95q-3.3 0-5.4-2.1-2.1-2.1-2.1-5.4 0-3.3 2.1-5.4 2.1-2.1 5.4-2.1 3.3 0 5.4 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 5.4 0 3.3-2.1 5.4-2.1 2.1-5.4 2.1ZM8 40v-4.7q0-1.9.95-3.25T11.4 30q3.35-1.5 6.425-2.25Q20.9 27 24 27q3.1 0 6.15.775 3.05.775 6.4 2.225 1.55.7 2.5 2.05.95 1.35.95 3.25V40Z" />
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48">
  <path d="M24 23.95q-3.3 0-5.4-2.1-2.1-2.1-2.1-5.4 0-3.3 2.1-5.4 2.1-2.1 5.4-2.1 3.3 0 5.4 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 5.4 0 3.3-2.1 5.4-2.1 2.1-5.4 2.1ZM8 40v-4.7q0-1.9.95-3.25T11.4 30q3.35-1.5 6.425-2.25Q20.9 27 24 27q3.1 0 6.15.775 3.05.775 6.4 2.225 1.55.7 2.5 2.05.95 1.35.95 3.25V40Z" />
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48">
  <path d="M24 23.95q-3.3 0-5.4-2.1-2.1-2.1-2.1-5.4 0-3.3 2.1-5.4 2.1-2.1 5.4-2.1 3.3 0 5.4 2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 5.4 0 3.3-2.1 5.4-2.1 2.1-5.4 2.1ZM8 40v-4.7q0-1.9.95-3.25T11.4 30q3.35-1.5 6.425-2.25Q20.9 27 24 27q3.1 0 6.15.775 3.05.775 6.4 2.225 1.55.7 2.5 2.05.95 1.35.95 3.25V40Z" />
</svg>
```